# My (Vba) Code only works with 1 variable in the list, and gives only blanks back when multiple variables used in listbox

Tags: vba, excel, filter, listboxitem

I've got a code that puts all the data of my Excel file (rows = 12,5k+ and columns = 97) in to a two-dimensional string. Then it loops through a certain column ("G") to list an listbox ("listbox1") with only unique findings. 
Then in the Userform the user can choose to select some of the found items and transform it to another listbox ("Listbox2") Then when the user hits the button (CommandButton4) I would like the code to filter the array on only the rows where in column "G" it is the same as in one (or more) given criteria in listbox2. 
It works when It has only one item in the listbox but when given two items in the listbox, it only returns everything blank.

Can some one please tell me what I'm doing wrong because I've no idea.

code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim arr2() As Variant
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim B_List As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, q As Long, r As Long, LastColumn  As Long, LastRow As Long
    q = 1
    r = 1

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ReDim arr2(1 To LastRow, 1 To LastColumn)

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            For j = 1 To LastColumn
                arr2(i, j) = .Cells(i, j).Value
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
            If ListBox2.List(j) = arr2(i, 7) Then
                'Later aan te passen
            Else
                For q = 1 To LastColumn
                    arr2(i, q) = ""
                Next q
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.ClearContents

    For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
        If arr2(i, 2) <> "" Then
            r = r + 1
            For j = LBound(arr2, 2) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(r, j).Value = arr2(i, j)

            Next j
        End If
        Debug.Print i, j, arr2(i, 7)
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend setting breakpoints at various locations through your code, so you can check if the variables contain what you expect them to. Also try stepping through your code so you can see if things are being overwritten or changed as expected (or unexpected). That should help to identify where the problems are originating in the code.

Comment: You shouldn't need to loop through sheet3's contents to dump the array back to sheet. you can just set the dynamic range to equal arr2

Comment: also try .additem with your ;list box see if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your second nested-loop:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox2.List(j) = arr2(i, 7) Then
            'Later aan te passen
        Else
            For q = 1 To LastColumn
                arr2(i, q) = ""
            Next q
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Suppose that our ListBox has 2 values, "First" and "Second".  For each row, you do the following:

> j = 0
>
> ListBox2.List(0) = "First"
>
> If Column G is "First", do nothing
>
> Otherwise, make the whole Row Blank  **Including if Column G = "Second"**
>
> **At this point, the *only* possible values for Column G are now "First" or Blank**
>
> j = 1
>
> ListBox2.List(1) = "Second"
>
> If Column G is "Second", do nothing **But, this cannot happen, because you have already changed any "Second" Rows to Blank**
>
> Otherwise, make the whole Row Blank
>
> **At this point, the Row will *always* be Blank**

I recommend having a Boolean test variable.  Set it to `False` at the start of each Row-loop, and set it to `True` if you find a match.  If it is *still* `False` after you check all ListBox items, **then** blank the row:

```
Dim bTest AS Boolean
For i = 1 To LastRow
    bTest = False 'Reset for the Row
    For j = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox2.List(j) = arr2(i, 7) Then
            bTest = True 'We found a match!
            Exit For 'No need to keep looking
        End If
    Next j
    If Not bTest Then 'If we didn't find a match
        For q = 1 To LastColumn
            arr2(i, q) = "" 'Blank the row
        Next q
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the fresh perspective, coudn't find it by myself.

Comment: @J.O.P.P. Looking at your code, you have a completely unused `B_List` Boolean - I can only assume you were initially going to use it for the test-case, but were distracted before you wrote that line and forgot :)